# SQL Query Calculate Quarterly data from monthly data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table given below

```
Year   Month   Pro   Revenue
2019 | Jan   | ABC |    1200
2019 | Feb   | ABC |    2451
2019 | Mar   | ABC |    6543
2019 | Apr   | ABC |    3987
2019 | May   | ABC |    4097
2019 | Jun   | ABC |    4587
2019 | Jul   | ABC |    3878
2019 | Aug   | ABC |    1098
2019 | Sep   | ABC |    3201
2019 | Oct   | ABC |    1209
2019 | Nov   | ABC |    4398
2019 | Dec   | ABC |    4517
```

Can someone pls help me here, i am not able to create a sql query  for the following

which quarter has the best revenue?

Comment: Pick a database any database but ONLY ONE database, preferably the one you are using

Comment: @RachitRastogi . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: What's wrong with `TOP`?

Comment: *"Do you have any idea how to create query"* not when you keep changing the RDBMS you are using. Check @RiggsFolly [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65797029/sql-query-calculate-quarterly-data-from-monthly-data#comment116333349_65797029) again, and only tag **one** RDBMS...

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(C.REVENUE)S_REVENUE,
 CASE
   WHEN C.MONTH IN('Jan','Feb','Mar') THEN 1
   WHEN C.MONTH IN('Apr','May','Jun')THEN 2
   WHEN C.MONTH IN('Jul','Aug','Sep')THEN 3
   ELSE 4
END AS QUART
FROM YOUR_TABLE AS C
GROUP BY 
 CASE
    WHEN C.MONTH IN('Jan','Feb','Mar') THEN 1
    WHEN C.MONTH IN('Apr','May','Jun')THEN 2
    WHEN C.MONTH IN('Jul','Aug','Sep')THEN 3
    ELSE 4
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be:

```
DECLARE @Revenue table ( [Year] int, [Month] varchar(3), Pro varchar(3), Revenue decimal(18,2) );
INSERT INTO @Revenue VALUES
    ( 2019, 'Jan', 'ABC', 1200 ),
    ( 2019, 'Feb', 'ABC', 2451 ),
    ( 2019, 'Mar', 'ABC', 6543 ),
    ( 2019, 'Apr', 'ABC', 3987 ),
    ( 2019, 'May', 'ABC', 4097 ),
    ( 2019, 'Jun', 'ABC', 4587 ),
    ( 2019, 'Jul', 'ABC', 3878 ),
    ( 2019, 'Aug', 'ABC', 1098 ),
    ( 2019, 'Sep', 'ABC', 3201 ),
    ( 2019, 'Oct', 'ABC', 1209 ),
    ( 2019, 'Nov', 'ABC', 4398 ),
    ( 2019, 'Dec', 'ABC', 4517 );

SELECT
    Qtr,
    SUM ( [Revenue] ) AS QtrRev
FROM @Revenue
CROSS APPLY (

    SELECT DATEPART ( quarter, CAST (
    CASE [Month]
        WHEN 'Jan' THEN '1'
        WHEN 'Feb' THEN '2'
        WHEN 'Mar' THEN '3'
        WHEN 'Apr' THEN '4'
        WHEN 'May' THEN '5'
        WHEN 'Jun' THEN '6'
        WHEN 'Jul' THEN '7'
        WHEN 'Aug' THEN '8'
        WHEN 'Sep' THEN '9'
        WHEN 'Oct' THEN '10'
        WHEN 'Nov' THEN '11'
        WHEN 'Dec' THEN '12'
    END + '/01/' + CAST ( [Year] AS varchar(4) ) AS date ) ) AS Qtr

) AS Qtr
WHERE
    [Year] = 2019
GROUP BY Qtr
ORDER BY
    QtrRev DESC;
```

Which returns

```
+-----+----------+
| Qtr |  QtrRev  |
+-----+----------+
|   2 | 12671.00 |
|   1 | 10194.00 |
|   4 | 10124.00 |
|   3 | 8177.00  |
+-----+----------+
```

To get the top performing quarter:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    Qtr,
    SUM ( [Revenue] ) AS QtrRev
FROM @Revenue...
```

Returns

```
+-----+----------+
| Qtr |  QtrRev  |
+-----+----------+
|   2 | 12671.00 |
+-----+----------+
```

Ideally, you would add a `Qtr` column that stores the quarter the revenue belongs to, or at the very least change your `Month` column to a `tinyint` and store the numeric value over a string representation of the month.